# Re-write the Riemann Roch theorem

Tags: algebraic-geometry

How can I write the Riemann-Roch Theorem with the following definitions:

Definition $1$: $\mathcal{F}$ is an *scheme of fractional ideals on $C$* if is coherent and for all $P\in C$, the stalk $\mathcal{F}_P$ is a $\mathcal{O}_P$-fractional ideal of $k(C)$, which is equivalent to:

(i) For all $P\in C$ is valid that:

a)  $\mathcal{F}_P\subset k(C)$

b)  $\exists f_P\in k(C)$ such that $f_P\cdot \mathcal{F}_P$ is an ideal of $\mathcal{O}_P$.

(ii) $\mathcal{F}_P=\mathcal{O}_P$ for almost every $P\in C$

Observation: Note that the sum point to point makes of the set of divisors of $C$, denoted by ${\rm Div}(C)$, a free abelian group over $C$.

Lets denote by ${\rm Frac}(C)$ the subcategory of ${\rm Coh}(C)$ which correspond to the schemes of fractional ideals of $C$.

The *grau* is defined on the folowwing way: If $\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G}\in {\rm Frac}(C)$ are such that $\mathcal{G}$ is a subscheme of $\mathcal{F}$, then
$$
\deg(\mathcal{F})-\deg(\mathcal{G}):=\sum_{P\in C}\dim_k(\mathcal{F}_P/\mathcal{G}_P)
$$
and we also define $\deg(\mathcal{O})=0$.

For $\mathcal{F}\in{\rm Frac}(C)$, the set that plays  ``$L(D)$" is the vectorial space of its global sections, i.e.,
$$
H^0(\mathcal{F})=H^0(C,\mathcal{F})=\Gamma(C,\mathcal{F}):=\{f\in k(C)\,|\, f\in\mathcal{F}_P\ \text{for all}\ P\in C\}
$$
and its dimention is denoted by $h^0(\mathcal{F})$.

Definition $2$: For each $\lambda\in\Omega_{k(C)/k}$, define $\omega_{\lambda}\in {\rm Frac}(C)$, such that for all $P\in C$ the stalk $\omega_{\lambda,P}$ is the greatest between the $\mathcal{O}_P$-fractional ideals $F$ in $k(C)$ such that $\sum_{\overline{P}|P}{\rm{Res}}_{\overline{P}}(f\lambda)=0$ for all $f\in F$. Besides, we have $\omega_C\cong\omega_{\lambda}$ for all $\lambda\in\Omega_{k(C)/k}$.